# How do I expose material-ui-classes outside of my components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We're mainly using material UI for providing better user experience in our apps. The big problem is the syncing the styles between MUI and plain html.

Is there a mechanism, for exposing material-ui css-classes, so that those would be usable also in html-notation?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <header class="appBar">We'd like to use MUI-style here</header>
        <div id="reactMountPoint"><!-- Mui components goes here --></div>
        <form>
            <button />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

So basically we'd like to use all MUI styles also outside of the react-apps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best idea, but it is possible, here's some documentation:

https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#global-css

> ### Global CSS
>
> We provide a custom implementation of the class name
>   generator for Material-UI needs: [`createGenerateClassName()`](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#creategenerateclassname-options-class-name-generator). As well as
>   the option to make the class names **deterministic** with the
>   `dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS` option. When turned on, the class names will
>   look like this:
>
> - development: `.MuiAppBar-root`
> - production: `.MuiAppBar-root`
>
> ⚠️ **Be very
>   cautious when using** `dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS`. We provide this option as
>   an escape hatch for quick prototyping, but you should avoid relying on
>   it for code running in production as it's very hard to keep track of
>   class name API changes. Global CSS is inherently fragile.

You would then have to somewhat closely match the structure of your plain HTML components to the material-ui components.

I might prefer to not use `dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS`, and to instead just manually copy any needed generated material-ui CSS to my own stylesheet. At least it will be stable. Particularly if it's only for a few components.

(This is for material-ui v1.x only, not v0.x.)

Comment: That's what I did. I just hate having duplicate code / functionality in my code. I was also considering dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS. Maybe the copying the necessary styles is the next best thing.

Comment: Mixing frameworks (React and non-React) in this way is always going to need a compromise, some CSS duplication isn't too bad. The ideal solution is of course to do everything with React, but I appreciate that can be difficult if you have a lot of older code.